# three.js - THREE.StereoEffect / webVR-boilerplate + THREE.Mirror

Tags: javascript, three.js, webvr

I'm trying to get a mirror effect working correctly in a project that is using  [webvr-boilerplate](https://github.com/borismus/webvr-boilerplate) when VREffect is active.

I tried (using r72dev and r72) to use THREE.Mirror:

```js
    //webVR-boilerplate + Mirror.js

    verticalMirror = new THREE.Mirror( renderer, camera, { clipBias: 0.03, textureWidth: 256, textureHeight: 256, color:0x889999 } );

    verticalMirrorMesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 10, 10 ), verticalMirror.material );

    verticalMirrorMesh.add( verticalMirror );

    scene.add( verticalMirrorMesh );

    // Request animation frame loop function
    function animate( timestamp ) {

          verticalMirror.render();

          // Update VR headset position and apply to camera.
          controls.update();
      
          // Render the scene through the manager.
          manager.render( scene, camera, timestamp );

          requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    }
```

The render targets stops updating when activating VR Mode and stereo viewing is active.

The mirror is behind the camera and I set a model spinning to observe the mirror behaviour.

Any thoughts of why this happens and possible way to fix it?
Am I missing some initialization parameters for the mirror or the stereoeffect?

[example](http://ruidorey.webfactional.com/)

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT : Seems the problem also not only happens with webvr-boilerplate but ALSO with StereoEffect.js and Mirror.js as I setup a scene using by a mirror to [three.js StereoEffect.js example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_effects_stereo.html) and still same problem..

[Stereo http://ruidorey.webfactional.com/stereo.png](http://ruidorey.webfactional.com/stereo.png)
[mirror WITH stereo effect - live example](http://ruidorey.webfactional.com/mirror-test-stereo.html)

[No Stereo http://ruidorey.webfactional.com/nostereo.png](http://ruidorey.webfactional.com/nostereo.png)
[mirror WITHOUT stereo effect - live example](http://ruidorey.webfactional.com/mirror-test-no-stereo.html)

Comment: Which VR HMD are we talking about? DK2? Cardboard for Android? Cardboard for iOS?

Comment: All of those... I tried with all

Comment: webvr-boilerplate uses VREffect, not StereoEffect.

Comment: Correct, correct, sorry for my confusion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mirror breaks when you enter VR mode because you have set the `WEBVR_FORCE_DISTORTION` flag. This causes webvr-boilerplate's WebVRManager to use its own CardboardDistorter shim (as opposed to distortion support in browsers that implement WebVR). This interferes with the mirror rendering.

CardboardDistorter hijacks the renderer and forces it to draw to a render target that belongs to the distorter. This prevents the mirror from using its own render target.

Ideally WebVRManager should be fixed so that it supports mirrors out of the box but you can work around this problem by storing the original render function and using it during the mirror rendering step:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
// Save the original render function, so that we can use it 
// even after CardboardDistorter hijacks the renderer.
var originalRenderFunc = renderer.render;

...

function animate(timestamp) {

    ...

    // In our animation loop, restore the original render 
    // function for the mirror to use.
    var hijackedRenderFunc = renderer.render;
    renderer.render = originalRenderFunc;

    verticalMirror.render();

    // Set the render function back to the hijacked version
    // so that CardboardDistorter can do its job.
    renderer.render = hijackedRenderFunc;

   ...

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I set the flag because gives me the distortion effect that happens on oculus and cardboard... If I unset it, it doesn't happen in desktop but still happens in dk2 and mobiles...

Comment: From what I infer, then the problem is the BarrelDistortion shader...
is there any way to have both shaders working correctly?

Comment: @Ruid'Orey I've edited my answer with a work around which should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on the code in your live example, not the code in your post.

The problem is that `StereoEffect` calls `renderer.clear()`, but it is clearing the mirror's previously-rendered `WebGLRenderTarget`.

One solution is to do something like the following:

```
verticalMirror.render();

renderer.setRenderTarget( null ); // add this line

effect.render( scene, camera );
```

three.js r.72

Comment: This works with the simplified live example but not with webvr-boilerplate since the boilerplate includes a lens distortion shader as well.

Comment: @WestLangley  as pointed by brianpeiris, I asked two questions here, as I wrongly assumed the problem to be with StereoEffect but was with VREffect (used by boilerplate), for which I'm sorry. 
Thank you anyway for your support on the second question!