# WebVR Boilerplate Problems - Manager not rendering in VRMode, Camera looks straight down, fullscreen renders only half of window

Tags: javascript, three.js, webvr

I'm trying to implement WebVR into a project that I've built in Three.js and I'm having difficulties getting it to function correctly.

A number of problems arise when I view the scene.

1. When VRMode is false my scene renders but when switching to VR Mode the scene suddenly stops rendering.  I can see the two stereoscopic windows but nothing else appears.
2. When I load my scene on desktop the camera points straight down.  Upon loading over a device the scene is flipped upside down.  I am telling the camera to look at the center of my image and it doesn't seem to have any effect.  It was working just fine before I fiddled with the controls and rendering to support the WebVR manager and VRControls.

   ```
       camera.position.set(-300, -800, 200);
       camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
       camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
   ```

I am able to set the position fine.

3. When I click the fullscreen button on the bottom of the GUI the screen splits into two halves.  The top half is black (my body bg and clearfix color is blue) and the lower half renders my scene.  I have an event listener that works fine when I manually resize the window so this has to be related to the VR manager.

Any idea what could be causing these errors?

Here is how I define my renderer:

```
var width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true
});

renderer.setSize(width, height);
renderer.setClearColor(0x1D76BB, 1);

// Effect and Controls for VR
effect = new THREE.VREffect(renderer);
controls = new THREE.VRControls(camera);
effect.setSize(width, height);


var manager = new WebVRManager(renderer, effect);
```

Here is a my animate function:

```
function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        if (controls) {
            controls.update();
        }

        if (manager.isVRMode()) {
            renderer.setRenderTarget(null); // add this line
            manager.render(scene, camera);
        } else {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

    }
```

My libraries came fresh from bower this morning so I know they are all up to date.

Comment: What device(s) are you using to reproduce this issue? What browsers?

Comment: Can you share your project code or reproduce the problem in a reduced test sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to guess what's going on without looking at the rest of your code.

I'm not sure if this is related, but the latest version of the WebVRManager class takes care of switching between VR and non-VR mode for you and it falls back to a normal renderer in 2D mode. So you don't need to check for `isVRMode` anymore and you don't need to call `renderer.render`. Just use `manager.render` and it will do the work for you. The manager now also handles resizing for you, so you probably shouldn't be doing that either.
Other than that, you seem to be using the manager correctly.

VRControls (in conjunction with webvr-polyfill, if you're using it) overrides the camera position and orientation, so setting it yourself will have no effect (unless you're overriding it after `controls.update`, in which case, the controls will have no effect). If you want to set the base camera transform, you can attach the camera to a "dolly" and set the dolly's transform instead:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);
var dolly = new THREE.Object3D();
dolly.add(camera);
dolly.position.z = 200;
dolly.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
dolly.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
dolly.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), Math.PI);
scene.add(dolly);

function animate(timestamp) {
    var timer = new Date().getTime() * 0.0002;
    dolly.position.x = Math.floor(Math.cos(timer) * 600);
    dolly.position.y = Math.floor(Math.sin(timer) * 600);
    controls.update();
    manager.render(scene, camera, timestamp);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

Note that you have to add the dolly to the scene and that you have to rotate the dolly on its Y axis, after you make it `lookAt` something since cameras look into the negative Z direction by default.

It may also be helpful to add an AxisHelper to the scene so that you can get a better sense of your bearings while you debug:

```
var axisHelper = new THREE.AxisHelper(200);
axisHelper.position.z = 100;
scene.add(axisHelper);
```

Lastly, if you are using webvr-polyfill, it can sometimes, depending on which devices you are using, render its own barrel distortion shader pass. So, if your project involves shaders, they might conflict with this shader pass and prevent your scene from rendering correctly, or at all, in VR mode. If this is the case, you may be able to workaround this by rendering your shaders before you call `manager.render` as I've described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32549777/22417

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I'm still not sure what's causing the render problems.

I ended up taking a lot of my code and inserting it into the boilerplate demo.  It's working fine over there so I'm just going to keep modifying that document by moving code from the broken version to the new one.

Comment: It should break eventually and then I'll know whats causing the error.

My mobile display is still flipping upside down.  Any thoughts here?  

You can find the code I'm working with here:

[PDS Cardboard](http://www.googledrive.com/host/0B_XkORRtWN2OcGstUjE5R0RRRWc/PDS_Cardboard/)

Comment: @Dig_Dig_Dig I've updated my answer based on the code you linked to. Assuming your intention was to have the camera rotate around the terrain while looking directly at the ground, the main change was to add a `rotateOnAxis` call to the dolly, so that the camera points in the right direction after the `lookAt`. Also, make sure you animate the dolly and not the camera, as I mentioned. Finally, I added a note about AxisHelper, since that helped me figure out the issue.

Comment: Another suggestion that might be helpful: It seems you're changing the camera's `up` vector simply because the terrain you're loading is rotated by 90 degrees. Instead of changing your entire coordinate reference, it may be easier just to rotate your terrain, so that you can continue with a normal frame of reference ("up" being in the positive Y direction): `plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2; // Rotate the plane so that its top surface points in the positive Y direction` and `plane.position.y = -150; // Move the plane just below the origin, while we're at it`.
```

Comment: The fix in my answer seems to work for me on desktop (using an Oculus DK2 and a WebVR browser) and on most Android web browsers (Firefox stable was a bit weird). If it doesn't work for you, let me know which mobile device and browser you're using.

Comment: One last comment: If my assumption about your intentions are correct, your app, as it's currently implemented might lead to a lot of nausea in VR. The dolly animation causes the user's point of view to move upwards, downwards and sideways (depending on which point of the animation you're in). All of these movements go against VR best practices. They are very unnatural movements, especially since users wont have an accompanying sense of physical movement. It's even more compounded, since the user is looking directly at the ground and their whole field of view is filled with a moving ground.

Comment: I'd encourage you to read through some of the VR best practice documents here: https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/intro-vr/latest/concepts/bp_app_motion/ and https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/intro-vr/latest/concepts/bp_app_simulator_sickness/#bp_app_fov_scale-d2615e218

Comment: Thanks Brian.  The final product will have a guided tour of the site that takes the user from one point of interest to the next.  The revolving camera is just a temporary set up until I can finish the code for the tour.  

I will take a look at these links and read up!